# Neither PUB key nor PRIV key: nested asn1 erro

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paypal, payment-gateway

I am getting An `OpenSSL::PKey::RSAError`  Neither PUB key nor PRIV key: nested asn1 error while integrating paypal gateway. 
Here is my code:

```
gw=:paypal_express 
paypal_options=YAML.load_file(Rails.root.join('config', 'paypal.yml'))[Rails.env] 
paypal_options[:pem]=File.read("#{Rails.root}/paypal_cert_pem.txt") 

gateway=ActiveMerchant::Billing::Base.gateway(gw).new(paypal_options)

gateway.set‌​up_purchase(200,:return_url => "xyz",:cancel_return_url => "xyz",:description => "Working good")
```

Comment: Could you give any details, maybe the code in the script you are using, or anything of that sort?

Comment: gw=:paypal_express
paypal_options=YAML.load_file(Rails.root.join('config', 'paypal.yml'))[Rails.env]
paypal_options[:pem]=File.read("#{Rails.root}/paypal_cert_pem.txt")
gateway=ActiveMerchant::Billing::Base.gateway(gw).new(paypal_options)gateway.setup_purchase(200,:return_url => "xyz",:cancel_return_url => "xyz",:description => "Working good")

Comment: Looks good. Could you add it to the question so it's easier to read? :)

Comment: Hi Peter, I have added. Please, do have a look.

Comment: Thanks for integrating the code into the question. Are you trying to connect from you localhost or remotely? Have you tried replacing the public key on both the client and the server instances?